# Mongoose get collection data if present the update otherwise insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to mongodb and mongoose with ExpressJS. It may be simple question but I dont success.

```
var BookCounter = new Schema({
    counter: {type: Number,},
    book: {type: String, min: 18}
});
```

this is the my schema and the following is the my question:

I want to check that xyz book is present or not

> if book is present

Then I have to update the book counter by one.

> otherwise

I have to insert new book.

Can you please help me ..

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an update operation **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** that uses the options **`upsert`** to create the document if it does not exist and the **`new`** option if set to true returns the newly created/modified document rather than the original, alongside the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set)** and **[`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#up._S_inc)** field update operators.

The following example demonstrates this:

```
var query = { "book": "xyz" },
    update = { "$inc": { "counter": 1 } },
    options = { "upsert": true, "new": true };

// Find the document
Book.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, result) {
    if (err) handleError(err);    
    else {
        // do something with the document
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
    }
});
```